# use python to get grid cell areas given an ellipsoid

Tags: python, geospatial

Given an ellipsoid with major semi-axis *a* and minor semi-axis *b*, and a regular lon-lat grid, what is the best way to get the areas of each grid cell? I would like to use python and preferably cartopy.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code now gives the exact areas without being too much more complicated (just need to treat the sphere differently)

```
def surf_area_on_sphere(lat0, lat1, delta_lon, r):
    """
    Function to get the area of a portion of a sphere 
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    lat0 : float or array
        lower limit(s) of latitude interval(s) in degrees
    lat1 : float or array
        upper limit(s) of latitude interval(s) in degrees
    delta_lon : float or array
        width of longitude interval(s) in degrees
    r : float
        radius
    
    Returns
    -------
    area : float or array
    """
    d2r = np.pi / 180.
    return d2r * delta_lon * r ** 2 * (
        np.sin(d2r * lat1) - np.sin(d2r * lat0))

def anti_deriv(lat, a, b):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    lat : float or numpy array
        Latitude in radians
    a : float
        major semi-axis
    b : float
        minor semi-axis

    Returns
    -------
    ad : float or numpy array
        value of the antiderivative with respect to z for
        1 / (2 * b) * sqrt(1 + ((a / b) ** 2 - 1) * (z / b) ** 2)
    """            
    r = np.sin(lat) # z /b
    g = np.sqrt(a ** 2 - b ** 2) / b
    return np.arcsinh(g * r) / g + r * np.sqrt(1 + (g * r) ** 2)

def surf_area_on_ellipsoid(lat0, lat1, delta_lon, a, b):
    """
    Function to get the area of a portion of an ellipsoid.
    Based on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid

    Parameters
    ----------
    lat0 : float or array
        lower limit(s) of latitude interval(s) in degrees
    lat1 : float or array
        upper limit(s) of latitude interval(s) in degrees
    delta_lon : float or array
        width of longitude interval(s) in degrees
    a : float
        major semi-axis
    b : float
        minor semi-axis
    
    Returns
    -------
    area : float or array
    """
    if a == b:
        return surf_area_on_sphere(lat0, lat1, delta_lon, a)
    assert(b < a)
    d2r = np.pi / 180.
    return .5 * d2r * delta_lon * a * b * (
        anti_deriv(d2r * lat1, a , b) - anti_deriv(d2r * lat0, a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximate solution

```
def surf_area_on_ellipsoid(lat0, lat1, delta_lon, a, b):
    """
    Function to be used to get approximate grid cell areas
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    lat0 : float or array
        lower limit(s) of latitude interval(s) in degrees
    lat1 : float or array
        upper limit(s) of latitude interval(s) in degrees
    delta_lon : float or array
        width of longitude interval(s) in degrees
    a : float
        major semi-axis
    b : float
        minor semi-axis
    
    Returns
    -------
    area : float or array
    """
    assert(b <= a)
    d2r = np.pi / 180.
    # latitude width in radians
    delta_lat = d2r * (lat1 - lat0)
    # central latitude in radians
    lat = .5 * d2r * (lat1 + lat0)
    # arc length in latitude direction
    ds_lat = delta_lat * np.hypot(a * np.sin(lat), b * np.cos(lat))
    # arc length in longitude direction
    ds_lon = a * np.cos(lat) * d2r * delta_lon
    return ds_lon * ds_lat
```

Here is an exact solution for the full ellipsoid to check it (from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid):

```
def surf_area_ellipsoid(a, b):
    """
    Exact formula for total area of an ellipsoid (for testing)
    Oblate spheroid case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : float
        major semi-axis
    b : float
        minor semi-axis
    
    Returns
    -------
    area : float
    """
    if a == b:
        return 4 * np.pi * a ** 2
    t = np.sqrt(a ** 2 - b ** 2)
    s = b ** 2 * np.arcsinh(t / b) / t
    return 2 * np.pi * a * (a +  s)
```

With half-degree resolution the numerical method agrees reasonably with the exact total area:

```
a = 1
for b in [1, .99, .9, .5, .1]:
    exact = surf_area_ellipsoid(a=a, b=b)
    lat = np.linspace(-90., 90., 360)
    sa = np.sum(surf_area_on_ellipsoid(lat[:-1], lat[1:], 360, a=a, b=b))
    print(sa, exact)

12.566410711226226 12.566370614359172
12.482719164468133 12.482679067595733
11.737538672449274 11.737498575531172
8.671922800413613 8.671882703345052
6.472242602987875 6.472202505854831
```

It is probably good enough, but it might be worth trying to do it exactly with the method of the test.